# Windows 10 computer can't see internal Dell RD1000 device

Tags: windows, drivers, bios, compatibility, hotplug

I have an internal (SATA) PowerVault Dell RD1000 device with some cartridges. In a Dell PowerEdge T610 server,with Windows Server 2012, the device works perfectly.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte-B250M-DS3H - support hot plug in BIOS.
Windows 10 v22H2.

When I enter to Setup, I see the RD1000 device but in Windows I can't. I installed many [RD1000 utilities](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000134541/installation-and-use-of-the-dell-powervault-rd1000-removable-hard-disk-drive) which according to the [manual](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powervault/powervault-rd1000_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) support Windows 7/8x, but they don't work even in Compatibility Mode. I get message

> This Update Package is not compatible with your system configuration

When I boot from a USB with a Windows install, I can't see the disk but if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and open the console, I can navigate through the disk, even play videos files from the disk!!

I think that these devices only run in Dell computers. My question is if anybody faced the same problem and if that has a solution.

Comment: I installed all utilities on that page, but it desn't work. Operating systems listed on that page range from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2019, but there is no desktop windows version.

Comment: *there is no desktop windows version* should be enough as a clue.

Comment: Ironically it seems to work without any additional drivers/software in any modern Linux distro, desktop or server oriented.